# Issues on importing multiple files

Tags: r

I am new to R. Currently I have spent hours on Youtube videos looking to import a folder of CSV files for my data analytics project. The following are my codes:

```
enter code here



 library(tidyverse) 
 library(fs)  
 library(purrr)
     
 directory_that_holds_files <- "/Users/users/Desktop/capstone.project/nasdaq_index_csv"
    
  nasdaq_indexes <- directory_that_holds_files%>%
     dir_ls()%>%
         map( 
            .f = function(path) {
               read_csv(
                   path, 
                   col_types = cols(
                     Date = col_double(),
                     Close/Last = col_double(),
                     Open = col_double(),
                     High = col_double(),
                     Low = col_double() 
                     )
                 )
           }
    )
```

Here's what happens when I run these codes:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fs)
library(purrr)

directory_that_holds_files <- "/Users/users/Desktop/capstone.project/nasdaq_index_csv"

  nasdaq_indexes <- directory_that_holds_files%>%
     dir_ls()%>%
         map( 
            .f = function(path) {
               read_csv(
                   path, 
                   col_types = cols(
                     Date = col_double(),
                     Close/Last = col_double(),
 **Error: unexpected '=' in:**
               **Date = col_double(),
               Close/Last ="**
               Open = col_double(),
**Error: unexpected ',' in "                Open = col_double(),"**
              High = col_double(),
**Error: unexpected ',' in "                High = col_double(),"**
              Low = col_double() 
              )
**Error: unexpected ')' in "                 )"**
           )
**Error: unexpected ')' in "              )"**
      }
**Error: unexpected '}' in "        }"**
     )
**Error: unexpected ')' in "    )"**
```

I have checked the brackets multiple times and I am pretty sure that the brackets are matched, yet the error messages appear. Extremely grateful if anyone could provide some insights on improving my codes.

My R studio version is 4.1.3

Update: [Here is the output of problems()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dvpG.png)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is with this line:

```
...
Close/Last = col_double(),
...
```

Convert this to

```
`Close/Last` = col_double(),
```

And that should fix your issue. This is because `R` doesn't recognize "/" as a valid character for naming variables. You need to tell `R` that the whole term is a variable.

Comment: Really appreciate your help, but once I edited my code and reran it again, there were warning messages like this:   
Warning messages:
                                                                                                                                                                                                         
1: One or more parsing issues, see `problems()` for details 
2: One or more parsing issues, see `problems()` for details

Comment: Could you show us the output of problems()?  Probably has something to do with coercing the variable to a certain type during reading